# What would be the size of Wallpaper for different screen sizes?

Tags: android, wallpaper

Currently iam using this piece of code to get width and height wallpaper
      WallpaperManager wpm = WallpaperManager.getInstance(this);

```
        float minH =  wpm.getDesiredMinimumHeight();
        float minW =  wpm.getDesiredMinimumWidth();
```

iam unable to set the image correctly.

Comment: What exactly is the question? It seems you have the screen size (which the title suggests you're searching)

Comment: I suggest you start using **dp**s and let Android do the scaling as needed. Possibly, use 9 patches, Drawables and / or VectorDrawables if you wnat to prevent OutOfMemory Exceptions